# Is there a way to take a configured entity reference field and attach it as-is in a custom module?

Tags: entities

I have an entity reference field that I've configured and have added to a content type. Is there a way to take that same field and attach it with it's configuration in a custom module? I can attach the entity reference field using "Entity reference autocomplete" but the problem is that I have it configured to use View Mode with an argument to filter the list. When I attach it using "Entity Reference Autocomplete", it's without the View Mode and argument. I need to be able to carry those forward. I have it attached like this:

```
  $form['my_entity_reference'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entityreference',
    '#title' => t('My Reference'),
    '#era_entity_type' => 'user',  // Mandatory.
    '#era_bundles' => array(), // Optional (Any bundle by default).
    '#era_cardinality' => 3,       // Optional (1 By default).
  );
```

Thank you.